# VSCode - XDebug connected to client but break points does not work

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug, wsl-2

I work on PHP application and I want to debug my website.
I'm working on IDE VSCode on Windows 10.
I use Docker to launch my website in WSL2.

I have configured XDebug in my php-fpm:7.3 container.

```
root@00376c075cd3:/var/www# php -version
PHP 7.3.18 (cli) (built: May 15 2020 13:33:15) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.18, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.8, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

On VSCode, I have configured my launch.json file (with extension phpdebug from

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I see in XDebug log that it's connected.

```
[6] Log opened at 2020-11-24 16:48:10
[6] I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
[6] I: Connected to client. :-)
[6] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.18" protocol_version="1.0" appid="6" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="2.9.8"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[6] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[6] Log closed at 2020-11-24 16:48:10
```

I put breakpoints on my index.php file: [breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT8Sf.png)

But my request is not stopped in VSCode.

Can you please help me to finish my XDebug configuration?

Thank you for your help.

Regards,
Anthony

Comment: `Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.` It is expected with this kind of settings. Based on Xdebug log you must have connected to the **php-fpm** that runs inside your docker/WSL2 (it also uses 9000 port by default). You need to use correct IP of your **host OS** (so Xdebug can connect FROM your docker/WSL2 TO you VSCode that runs on Windows). I suggest checking some ready-made guides on how to configure Xdebug/Docker image in such cases. You may also check here for possible hints: https://learnxdebug.com/

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried with localhost and with WSL2 IP, but not yet with my host OS IP. It works very well now. Thank you very much @LazyOne and thank you for your link, very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @LazyOne.
I put your comment as answer. :-)

"
Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000. It is expected with this kind of settings. Based on Xdebug log you must have connected to the php-fpm that runs inside your docker/WSL2 (it also uses 9000 port by default). You need to use correct IP of your host OS (so Xdebug can connect FROM your docker/WSL2 TO you VSCode that runs on Windows). I suggest checking some ready-made guides on how to configure Xdebug/Docker image in such cases. You may also check here for possible hints: learnxdebug.com
"